# DBeaver zebra goes missing

Tags: dbeaver

**System information:**

```
OS: Manjaro Linux x86_64 
Kernel: 6.6.7-1-MANJARO 
Packages: 1816 (pacman) 
Shell: zsh 5.9 
Resolution: 1920x1080, 1920x1080 
DE: Plasma 5.27.10 
WM: KWin 
Theme: [Plasma], Breeze [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Tela [Plasma], Tela [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: konsole 
CPU: Intel i7-4790 (8) @ 4.000GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GT 730 
GPU: Intel HD Graphics 
Memory: 5081MiB / 19852MiB
```

**Dbeaver 23.2.2.202310151102**

the grid looks like this
[image]

but if you click on the line the zebra colors disappear
[image]

Why do colors disappear and how to fix it?

reinstalled, deleted all settings directories

i did a factory reset

[image]